# Program for choosing computers to run X clients on - what are such programs called?

Tags: xorg, x11, software-rec, hp-ux

At my college some 20 years ago they ran HPUX and had several X-terminals (terminals with graphic-cards that ran an X server, but left the running of X clients to the main computer). The college had several servers, so rather than getting the normal Display Manager screen with GUI login and password prompt, you got a list of servers with their load-averages. Once you selected one of the server, you got the usual Display Manager prompt.

What is the generic name of such a choosers? (I mean "generic" in the way WindowManager is generic as opposed to mwm, fvwm or afterstep and DisplayManager is generic as opposed to xdm, mdm and asdm).

Is it a specific program, or something like an option to the DisplayManager? If it's a specific program, which are available? Are there any which is part of the standard X packages (or perhaps as a contrib)?

---

Wordlist (what I mean):

- DisplayManager: Used with GUI-logins, prompts for username and password.
- WindowManager: Draws window-borders, allows resizing, moving, minimizing etc. Often with extra functions (like DesktopManager).
- DesktopManager: Allow switching between separate and/or parts of an oversized desktop.
- DesktopEnviroment: Combination of WM, DesktopManager and a set of commonly used utilities and applicatins; all with a similar look and feel, all integrated (more or less) together, often with some standards about menu choices and buttons (easy to recognize between different programs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you are looking for is [X display manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29).

Apologies for too short a response, I meant to expand, saying that everything you are looking for is available at that wiki page.  It is just a DisplayManager that is configured to show remote options.  Look at the section on XDMCP for specifics on how that works.

If you want an example of how to configure a specific DisplayManager.  I'm sure someone can work on that.